# Failing to retrieve reflection object in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, reflection

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and [Balanced Payment's PHP client library](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php) and I'm getting an error about not being able to retrieve the reflection object. Here is the error I'm receiving.

```
Error: ReflectionClass::getProperties() [<a href='http://php.net/reflectionclass.getproperties'>reflectionclass.getproperties</a>]: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the reflection object
```

Here is the code in question

```
$ref = new ReflectionObject($var);
$reflectionProperties = $ref->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED); //this is the line that throws the error
```

When I print $ref it shows

```
    ReflectionObject Object
(
    [name] => Httpful\Response
)
```

Also if I print $var I can see the object's contents.

```
Httpful\Response Object
(
    [body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => Bad Request
            [category_code] => request
            [additional] => 
            [status_code] => 400
            [description] => Invalid field [email] - "1.2.3.abc@4.5.6" must be a valid email address as specified by RFC-2822 Your request id is OGM0c63b5baa56111e3a3ac02a1fe52a34c.
            [category_type] => request
            [_uris] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

 ....
```

Why is PHP not able to retrieve the reflection object despite being able to print the contents? I can access the individual values as wel

ex:

```
echo $var->body->status;   //displays "Bad Request"
```

I'm not too experienced with the reflection class, so please let me know if you guys need more information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that class either, but I found in http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php : "Caution
If you're overwriting the constructor, remember to call the parent's constructor before any code you insert. Failing to do so will result in the following: Fatal error: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the reflection object"

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the Reflection error is that, this is caused in lower version of Cakephp. Its better if you upgrade to 4.1

The Reflectionclass is called because the older version of CakePHP is unable to handle the warning/error.

In the above case  **echo $var->body->status;** may not be existing.So once u update to newer version of Cakephp than u will be shown warning or error

Comment: ` Its better if you upgrade to 4.1` you mean by cakephp version?

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.x the correct way is below:

```
$ref = new \ReflectionObject($var);
$reflectionProperties = $ref->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
```

Warning for "/" before ReflectionObject and ReflectionProperty